# Developing application with Qt + QGIS or with PyQGIS + QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qt

I'm a n00b developer in the GIS arena, developing a desktop application that will have a window to display map data, along with other windows to perform operations over the data. I also would like to display a layer with Google Maps tiles, were overlay data will be displayed.

I understand that there are two major options to build this application if one is to use QGIS for the cartography part:

1. Qt + QGIS
2. PyQGIS + QGIS

Can anybody give guidance for the reasons to choose one options over the other one? Some topics I'm interested to consider are:

- Differences in performance;
- Code maintainability and extendability.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Qt is a GUI library, you have PyQt that allows you to build gui applications in Python. You can also develop C++ application with Qt. For both you have QGIS API (PyQGIS and qgis api). So I assume that you need only choose between Python and C++.

Comment: Yes, basically that's it. I was unsure if the PyQGIS and QGIS API would provide the same capabilities. From your answer, I understand that both API are equivalent, so it's just a matter of choosing the language (C++ or Python). Thanks for your comment, which clarified my mind.